# input radio 'checked' saves, but select option 'selected' doesn't

Tags: metabox, taxonomy, terms

So I followed a tutorial on how to create a meta box w/ the taxonomy terms shown in radio buttons. (Tutorial here for others if interested: http://wp.tutsplus.com/tutorials/creative-coding/how-to-use-radio-buttons-with-taxonomies/)

My main goal is to create it to be a drop down. However, when converting the input radio styles to select option, the selected option does not save. Here is the code comparing the two:

```
      <div id="taxonomy-<?php echo $taxonomy; ?>" class="categorydiv">
          <!-- Display taxonomy terms -->
            <div id="<?php echo $taxonomy; ?>checklist" class="list:<?php echo $taxonomy?> categorychecklist form-no-clear">

              <!-- Display taxonomy terms -->
                <select id="select-taxonomy">
                    <?php foreach($terms as $term){ 
                      $id = $taxonomy.'-'.$term->term_id;
                        $value= (is_taxonomy_hierarchical($taxonomy) ? "value='{$term->term_id}'" : "value='{$term->term_slug}'");
                    echo "<option id='in-$id' name='{$name}'".selected($current,$term->term_id,false)." {$value} />$term->name</option>";
                  } ?>
                </select>
              <!-- Display taxonomy terms -->
                <div id="radio-taxonomy">
                <?php foreach($terms as $term){ 
                  $id = $taxonomy.'-'.$term->term_id;
                    $value= (is_taxonomy_hierarchical($taxonomy) ? "value='{$term->term_id}'" : "value='{$term->term_slug}'");
        echo "<label class='selectit'>";
        echo "<input type='radio' id='in-$id' name='{$name}'".checked($current,$term->term_id,false)." {$value} />$term->name<br />";
                      echo "</label>";
              } ?>
              </div>

            </div>
        </div>
```

The only thing I can think of that is causing the selection not to save is change the input radio to an  element, or it may be changing ".checked" to ".selected"

Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks,
Roc.

Comment: You say the data does not save but you are talking, mostly, about the display-- the `checked` function. "Saving" the data, and "displaying" the saved data are different things. Have you confirmed that the data does not save to the database?

Comment: No the data is not being saved. If the input is saved via the radio button, both values in the drop down and input radio are selected/displayed on page refresh. However, if when the radio is removed and the value is selected via drop down, the data is not changed upon refresh. This is also confirmed on the taxonomy term wp-list-table, where the post is not changed to the new selected term.

Comment: Nothing you posted involves the actual saving of data. The script/tutorial mentioned uses Javascript to do that so you should have a corresponding mechanism. If the data is not saving, that is where the problem is. [edit] your question to include that code.

Comment: I removed the js and the saving option for the input radio still works, so I concluded that may not be the problem. The javascript clears the selected input on the second tab. I will take a look at it again though.

Comment: Ok, now the saving ___works___? Or do you mean that the `select` menu still shows up? Do you have some other mechanism for saving the data? Something hooked to `save_post` maybe (which the tutorial mentions but does not pursue)?

Comment: Thanks for the help @s_ha_dum. 

Reference to what is talked about below: [link](http://postimg.org/image/y0grj67ll/)

Attached is the new revision I did to the code, removing all of the unnecessary codes I didn't need. If I Use the <input> element, it still saves the selected term even if the type is a radio or checkbox.

All I literally did was change the <input type radio> to <option>, as well as change "checked" to "selected" (compare line 46 & 56)

I have not added any save_post function or anything. I assume this may be the problem since the default metabox uses the input element?

Comment: Haha, @s_ha_dum I apologize for that. It was coming out ugly in Pastebin. Here is the code snippet. [link](http://pastebin.com/ERj31n8N)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It was a long way around to get there but you basically have a markup error. You didn't name your select. You should have:

```
<select id="select-taxonomy" name="<?php echo $name ?>"> // <-- here is the change
  <?php foreach($terms as $term) {
    $id = $taxonomy.'-'.$term->term_id;
    $value= (is_taxonomy_hierarchical($taxonomy) ? "value='{$term->term_id}'" : "value='{$term->term_slug}'");
      echo "<option id='in-$id' ". selected($current,$term->term_id,false) ." {$value} />$term->name</option>";
    } ?>
</select>
```

You don't name the individual options. You name the `select` itself. With that change, it works just fine.

Comment: WOW - YOU A GREAT! So, it was just that minimal extra attribute to the <select>? How did you recognize that, that was the problem? I was killing myself since 5 AM last night, and then woke up at 10 to come back at it.

Comment: I looked at `var_dump($_POST)` and couldn't find what I expected, so I went back and worked out why.